# Oauth 2.0 run flow for Youtube Data Api v3 not work - cache problem?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to upload videos to youtube via command line (prompt) using the following code in python and the google api "**Youtube Data Api v3**".

When the code is executed for the first time, the **Oauth 2.0 run flow** start.
A screen appears in the prompt asking for the *user's permission* to upload videos to the channel automatically.

Giving permission, is created a file with the token, which will avoid the confirmation screen in next runs.
I did these steps with a **google cloud account and youtube channel** and it worked.

**But now it doesn't work ANYMORE.**

```
import os
import json
import sys
import time
import http.client  
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised. 
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)  

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE ="api-google/client_secret_xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"


# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the API Console
https://console.cloud.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
        scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
        message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
        http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
    tags = None
    if options.keywords:
        tags = options.keywords.split(",")

    body=dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=options.title,
            description=options.description,
            tags=tags,
            categoryId=options.category,
            chennelId= "xxx"  # id youtube channel             
        ),
        status=dict(
            privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus,
            madeForKids=False,
            selfDeclaredMadeForKids=False
        )
    )

    # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
    )

    resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    
    while response is None:
        try:
            print("Uploading file...")
            status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if 'id' in response:
                    print("Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id'])
                else:
                    exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
                error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,e.content)
            else:
                raise
        except (RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e):
            error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

        if error is not None:
            print(error)
            retry += 1
            if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
                exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

            max_sleep = 2 ** retry
            sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
            print("Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds)
            time.sleep(sleep_seconds)


#upload video
def carico_short(path_video, folder_video):
     
    percorso_cartella = os.path.join(path_video, folder_video) 
    video_youtube = os.path.join(percorso_cartella, "video_youtube.mp4")  
    
    class ArgsNamespace:
        file = video_youtube
        title = "title"
        description = "content"
        category = "24" #24 è intrattenimento, prima era 22
        keywords = "shorts, curiosity"
        privacyStatus = "public"

    args = ArgsNamespace()     

    try:                        
        youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)        
        initialize_upload(youtube, args)                            
    except HttpError as e:  # Definisci e come un'eccezione HttpError
        print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))


# code to upload the video
cartella_output = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\canale youtube\\video-4-dopo-non-pubblicati"
carico_short(cartella_output, "folder")
```

Now i have **NEW** cloud console account and **new** youtube channel.
But the computer is the same.

If i execute the code the **run flow** does not work: **the authorization request does not appear in the prompt** (that should appears the first time)

And i have this error:

```
C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access myscript.py-oauth2.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
```

**EDIT**

```
C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255:    UserWarning: Cannot access myscript.py-oauth2.json:     No such file or directory
 warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Giovanni\Desktop\canale youtube\myscript.py", line 258, in carico_short
   youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  File "C:\Users\Giovanni\Desktop\canale youtube\myscript.py", line 99, in get_authenticated_service
   credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)
  File "C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\tools.py", line 195, in run_flow
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(getattr(logging, flags.logging_level))
AttributeError: 'ArgsNamespace' object has no attribute 'logging_level'
```

I suspect that google/youtube has some cache.

Maybe for YouTube the computer shows the authorization of the old account?
Is that so? how can I delete it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The "error" you posted is only a `UserWarning`, so it's not the problem here. Can you update the question with the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: @LukeSavefrogs done

Comment: Ty, as you can see it is stuck at the `run_flow` call, which means that at least **tried** to show the authentication window

Comment: noooo.... I assure you that no authentication window appears in the console but only errors.
Why is it stuck in the run_flow call? Why doesn't any authentication window appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message and the [`run_flow` code](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/50d20532a748f18e53f7d24ccbe6647132c979a9/oauth2client/tools.py#L142), it seems that if the `logging_level` arg is not found, then it is taken from the CLI.

Try to update the `ArgsNamespace` class like this:

```py
class ArgsNamespace:
    file = video_youtube
    title = "title"
    description = "content"
    category = "24" #24 è intrattenimento, prima era 22
    keywords = "shorts, curiosity"
    privacyStatus = "public"
    logging_level = "INFO"
```

### Even better

Even better, use the flow as it was meant to...

- Use the `ArgsNamespace` class to store the CLI flags that you want to override (in this case only `logging_level`) and `UploadOptions` to store the upload options you will use in your function
- Define both classes as `dataclass`es (no need to instantiate the object)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

# [...]

@dataclass
class ArgsNamespace:
    logging_level = "INFO"

@dataclass
class UploadOptions:
    file = video_youtube
    title = "title"
    description = "content"
    category = "24" #24 è intrattenimento, prima era 22
    keywords = "shorts, curiosity"
    privacyStatus = "public"

try:                        
    youtube = get_authenticated_service(ArgsNamespace)
    initialize_upload(youtube, UploadOptions)                            
except HttpError as e:  # Definisci e come un'eccezione HttpError
    print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```